# Can an authentication cookie be stolen if it's issued by a server over SSL?

Tags: asp.net, ssl, forms-authentication

Assume all communication between the client and the server is over SSL and "requireSSL=true" is set on the cookie.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is encrypting session id (or other authenticate value) in cookie useful at all?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840559/is-encrypting-session-id-or-other-authenticate-value-in-cookie-useful-at-all) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22880/what-is-the-best-way-to-prevent-session-hijacking

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS is [HTTP over TLS/SSL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818), which establishes the SSL/TLS connection before exchanging any HTTP messages.

Provided that both parties are configured correctly and that the client verifies the certificate, the SSL/TLS tunnel will protect the HTTP traffic against MITM attacks and eavesdropping.

This should prevent any party between the browser and the server from seeing that cookie. In addition, if this is a secure cookie (with the [`secure` flag](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/100/2435), which might be configured with `requireSSL=true`), the browser should only send it back on HTTPS request (if your site uses both HTTP and HTTPS). (It might be useful to set `httpOnly` on your cookie too to prevent from attacks involving scripts.)

Answer (score 0):

Teorically not, only can be stolen by:

1. bug in the browser
2. man in the middle attack
3. weak cypher algorithm